# Why is `.Select(...).Last()` optimized, but `.Select(...).Last(...)` not?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Consider the following enumerator:

```
var items = (new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }).Select(x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"inspect {x}");
    return x;
});
```

This yields the elements `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, printing them as they are consumed.

When I call the `Last` method on this enumerator, it triggers a fast path which only accesses a single element:

```
items.Last();
```

```
inspect 5
```

But when I pass a callback to `Last`, it loops through the whole list from the beginning:

```
items.Last(x => true);
```

```
inspect 1
inspect 2
inspect 3
inspect 4
inspect 5
```

Looking through the .NET Core source code, I find that:

- [`Last(IEnumerable<T>)` forwards to `TryGetLast(IEnumerable<T>, out bool)`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/f74b39562ad0e3b33715172d48eced02c7ca384f/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Last.cs#L13);
- [`TryGetLast(IEnumerable<T>, out bool)` has a fast path for `IPartition<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/f74b39562ad0e3b33715172d48eced02c7ca384f/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Last.cs#L46-L49);
- And since [`ArraySelectIterator<T>` implements `IPartition<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/f74b39562ad0e3b33715172d48eced02c7ca384f/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Select.SpeedOpt.cs#L72), this fast path is triggered and all is well.

On the other hand:

- [`Last(IEnumerable<T>, Func<T, bool>)` forwards to `TryGetLast(IEnumerable<T>, Func<T, bool>, out bool)`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/f74b39562ad0e3b33715172d48eced02c7ca384f/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Last.cs#L24)
- This has fast paths for [`OrderedEnumerator` and `IList<T>`, but not `ArraySelectIterator<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/f74b39562ad0e3b33715172d48eced02c7ca384f/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Last.cs#L83-L140).
- Therefore it takes the slow path and iterates from the beginning.

This explains *how* the callback case is not optimized. But it doesn't explain *why*.

Conceptually, if at least one element satisfies the predicate (which is likely in practice), then iterating backward may allow for exiting the loop early.

It doesn't seem difficult to implement either: from what I've seen, all it takes is an additional method on `IPartition<T>`.

The lack of optimization can also be surprising. Since these overloads share the same name, one might assume that they are also optimized in a similar way. (At least that's what I thought.)

Given these reasons to optimize this case, why did the authors of LINQ choose not to do that?

Comment: Maybe you should mentioned this in a post on github, i am not sure we can help you here other than agree or say *hmm*

Comment: @TheGeneral: Well, we could point out flaws in the reasoning (I did not find any, though), and it is well known that some .NET language designers *do* read and answer questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Let me quote Stephen Toub, who said this on another optimization suggestion: "With any query processing system, there are potentially an infinite number of optimizations that can be introduced to special case this or that pattern. Each of those optimizations adds code and complexity. Our goal should be to optimize the important ones, based on real use cases, as all such optimizations add cost for every other use, even if it's just in increased binary size, increased JIT time, etc., plus the on-going maintenance costs associated with the code for the additional special-casing."

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with the reasoning. Open up a thread on github and see what those cool kids say, you never know you might get an .Net Core optimization in a future version that you can attribute to your self. let us know how you go.. Also +1 for the Stehpen Toub comment from @sloth

Comment: @TheGeneral Wouldn't adding that optimization be a breaking change though? It's bad style, but some code could depend on the `Select` callback being invoked for every element. I was hesitant to post on GitHub for this reason.

Comment: @LambdaFairy - but the existing optimizations you've found for `OrderedEnumerable` and `IList<T>` already break the "contract" of it evaluating the predicate on all elements working forwards through the list. So anyone relying on e.g. a mutating predicate is already working on shaky ground.

Comment: Because [premature optimisation is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/102446). It's not clear why this optimisation belongs in the 3%?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but perhaps worth mentioning that if someone *needs* it to fast path, they could always write their own `Last` extension method that delegates to the standard implementation when necessary

Answer (score 2):

`Last()` can be always optimized for collections that allow access to the last element of the collection in constant time (`O(1)`). For those collections, instead of iterating all the collection and returning the last element, you can just access the last element directly.

> Conceptually, if at least one element satisfies the predicate (which is likely in 
>   practice), then iterating backward may allow for exiting the loop early.

That assumption is way too far fetched for a generic implementation of `Last(Func<T,bool>)`. You can't assume that the last element that satisfies the predicate is closer to the end of the collection in general. That *optimization* works well for your example (`Last(x=>true)`), but for every such example there can be an oposite example where that *optimization* performs worse (`Last(x=>false)`).

Comment: "*You can't assume that the last element that satisfies the predicate is closer to the end of the collection in general*" that is not really the point. Finding the last element moving forward means you have to look at all elements anyway

Comment: @Muscicapa Your answer is contradicted by the framework itself, which does loop backward if the enumerable is an `IList<T>`.